# JQuery DOM Line plugin при ресайзе окна

Tags: jquery, dom, responsive

Использую такой плагин [jQuery DOM Line plugin](http://gilmoreorless.github.io/jquery-dom-line/) для построения кривых линий по двум точках. Нужно, что бы при ресайзе окна (когда меняются координаты точек по которым строится кривая) линия переносилась на новые координаты.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  windowSize(); 
  $(window).resize(windowSize); 
});

function windowSize(){ 
    /* вычисляем координаты точек */    
    var point1 = {x:$(".point-1-1").offset().left, y:$(".point-1-1").offset().top},
        point2 = {x:$(".point-2-1").offset().left, y:$(".point-2-1").offset().top};

    /* запускается скрипт который строит кривую по двум точкам: от point1 до point2 */    
    $.line(point1, point2);  
};
```

Сейчас при ресайзе окна кривая постоянно клонируется (из-за того, что изменяются координаты и постоянно запускается скрипт $.line(point1, point2); ). Подскажите как правильно решить вопрос. То есть что бы при  $(window).resize скрипт розрушал кривую построенную на неактуальных координатах и оставлял ту, которая построенная на последних. Как то так )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В документации это не сказано, но скрипт по умолчанию **[создает элементы с классом jquery-line](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/gilmoreorless/jquery-dom-line/master/jquery.domline.js)** (посмотрите на **$.line.defaults**), соответственно код будет таким:

```
function windowSize(){ 
    /*вычисляем координаты точек*/    
    var point1 = {x:$(".point-1-1").offset().left, y:$(".point-1-1").offset().top},
        point2 = {x:$(".point-2-1").offset().left, y:$(".point-2-1").offset().top};
    /*удаляем старые линии*/
    $('.jquery-line').remove();
    /*запускается скрипт который строит кривую по двум точкам: от point1 до point2*/    
    $.line(point1, point2);  
};
```